# Migration tool took more than the expected time to finish the deployment

Tags: deployment, validation, migration-tool, performance, continuous-integration

Validations and deployments via migration tool to a sandbox took more than the expected time to  finish the deployment.

Total deployment/validation time supposed to be roughly 30 minutes and suddenly it started increasing the deployment/validation time. Today it took 156 minutes to complete a deployment. Could someone give us an insight about what's causes this delays and why?

Deployment completes though it takes nearly 3 hours to complete

Comment: what was your instance and when it happened ? I can see from status that some SFDC instances had service disruption yesterday

Comment: From working on [Gearset](https://gearset.com), we see that there can be 'variable' performance at times.

Are you on the same instance as normal, and have you moved API version recently?

Comment: @Himansu my instancce is cs25, seems this instance was fine

Comment: @Kevin yes we moved version recently 33 to 35!